# could not find the following boost libraries

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2015, cmake-gui, shark-ml

I am not able to figure out why am I getting this error.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1753 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.48.0

Boost include path: D:/Shark/boost_1_48_0

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

      boost_system
      boost_date_time
      boost_filesystem
      boost_program_options
      boost_serialization
      boost_thread
      boost_unit_test_framework

 No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
 directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
 Boost.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:146 (find_package)


 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:154 (message):
 Please make sure Boost 1.48.0 is installed on your system
```

It says, Unable to find requested boost library. But I have installed boost 1.48.0 and build it using Visual studio console, and have passed `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=D:/Shark/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib` and `BOOST_ROOT=D:/Shark/boost_1_48_0`.

Answer (score 0):

CMake's `FindBoost` macros look for the libs in various spots based on the compiler your using. Even if you specify `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, you still have to conform to the standards the `FindBoost` macro expects for filenames ie:

```
${Boost_LIB_PREFIX}boost_${COMPONENT}${_boost_COMPILER}${_boost_MULTITHREADED}${_boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG}-${Boost_LIB_VERSION}
${Boost_LIB_PREFIX}boost_${COMPONENT}${_boost_COMPILER}${_boost_MULTITHREADED}${_boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG}
${Boost_LIB_PREFIX}boost_${COMPONENT}${_boost_MULTITHREADED}${_boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG}-${Boost_LIB_VERSION}
${Boost_LIB_PREFIX}boost_${COMPONENT}${_boost_MULTITHREADED}${_boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG}
${Boost_LIB_PREFIX}boost_${COMPONENT} )
```

Example filenames matching this template for visual studio 2013 (aka msvc 12)

```
$BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR/boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58.dll
$BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR/boost_atomic-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll
```

You'll note that the `mt` for multithreaded build and the `gd` to indicate it's a debug build. FindBoost is fussy and will look for the debug build if your CMake project has a CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

Additionally if your building multithreaded you'll need to define:

```
Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED=ON
```

If your still having trouble you define: `Boost_DEBUG=1`  and you'll see a lot of additional output about how and where FindBoost is searching.

Comment: One quick question, do I need to build the boost library and pass the path of binary build as a result (as I did here) or can I just pass the path of source of those library, store in `boost_1_48_0\libs`

Comment: You need the libraries. If you don't want to build them you can always grab the prebuilt binaries from [sourceforge] (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)

Answer (score 0):

I was building the boost library by downloading source file. The problem was it was not creating .dll (only .lib).

I downloaded boost binary and installed it from installer to get those files, and set the path `BOOL_LIBRARYDIR=C:/local/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0` and `BOOL_ROOT=C:/local/boost` to make it done.